# Why do we talk about "everybody vs nobody" scenarios in causal inference?

Tags: causality, treatment-effect

Researcher A and researcher B survey mothers in Germany and ask them:

$T =$ Whether they smoked during their pregnancy

$Y =$ The birthweight of their baby

$\boldsymbol{X} =$ All kinds of things that should be controlled for when estimating a causal effect from $T$ to $Y$

(1) Researcher A reports that “If every pregnant woman in Germany smoked, the average birthweight in Germany would be lower by 200g than if none of them smoked”. Anyone you ask will tell you this is a correct interpretation of the ATE estimate.

(2) Researcher B reports that "Smoking during pregnancy causes lower birthweights. On average, 200g lower." Anyone you ask will tell you this is also a correct interpretation of the ATE estimate.

However:

(3) Since the statement in (1) is about an average, the correct take-away of this statement for a pregnant woman in Berlin debating whether to smoke or not is obviously not that her baby will be exactly 200g lighter if she smokes.

(4) But! Even if she understands this, *it is still unclear how the statement should influence her decision*, because she does not live in a Germany where every pregnant woman will magically follow her lead in smoking or not smoking. If she decides to smoke, the real Germany where she will do so is a very different place from the theoretical Germany in (1), where every pregnant woman smokes and gives everyone a nice dose of second-hand smoke everywhere the go.

(5) The statement of researcher B, on the other hand, refers unambiguously to the real-world Germany.

The statement in (1) is mathematically correct and comes from the definition $ATE = E[Y(1)] – E[Y(0)]$.

I think the statement in (2) follows from the fact that (under ignorability): $E[Y(1)] – E[Y(0)] = E[Y|T=1, \boldsymbol{X}] - E[Y|T=0, \boldsymbol{X}]$. Estimates for $E[Y|T=1, \boldsymbol{X}]$ and $E[Y|T=0, \boldsymbol{X}]$ then tell the German woman unambiguously that, controlling for all other relevant factors, the average baby from a smoker is lighter than the average baby from a non-smoker in real-world Germany.

**Question: why do so many papers talk like Researcher A in interpreting results, when that is just how the math works and not the question anyone was hoping to answer?**

Disclaimer: I can see that in some studies, the everybody/nobody could be the actual research question. For example, everyone gets free school lunch vs no one gets free school lunch. My question is about using the language of Researcher A when it does not seem to match the research objective. No medical researcher is sitting in their office thinking "Hmmmm... I wonder what would happen if every pregnant woman in the world smoked".

Comment: Wording of Statement 2 is more natural interoperation of ATE. Not sure if we can use everybody or nobody qualifiers: intuitively I think they would actually invalidate or rule out existence of control group. There is also personalised approaches,  Mueller & Pearl: [Personalized Decision Making -- A Conceptual Introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.09558)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Discussion of aggregate effects is common in population health studies

Most academic research on human behaviour aims to be useful to inform decision-making.  This can occur at different levels of influence, from informing the decisions of individuals in how they act in their own personal lives, to informing the decisions of policy-makers, regulators, professionals, etc.  A study on the effects of smoking on pregnancy could potentially inform the behaviour of pregnant mothers, but it could also potentially inform the behaviour of doctors, medical boards, public health bodies, cigarette-advertising regulators, corporate executives, politicians, etc.  The latter are typically concerned with the aggregate effects of a behaviour on a larger segment of society than a single individual.

One reason that researchers choose to frame their results in the way illustrated by Researcher A is that they wish to couch the issue in *social terms* and thereby appeal to people who can influence large-scale behaviour in their society, not just individual mothers who get to choose whether or not to smoke during pregnancy.  This type of framing feeds naturally into *policy questions* that are informed by consideration of the aggregated effects of behavioural change in a whole society or a large segment of society.  An individual mother might find the statement by Researcher B more useful, but a person working in population health research or policy is likely to find the statement by Researcher A more useful.

Now ask yourself, who is most likely to pay attention to an academic study on smoking and pregnancy (or derivative works that incorporate this information)?  An individual woman-on-the-street who smokes and falls pregnant, or a medical board?  An individual woman-on-the-street who smokes and falls pregnant, or a public health body that gives advice on cigarette regulation?  Etc.

From a mathematical perspective, the statement by Researcher B is giving the inferred causal effect on an individual and the statement by Researcher A is then extrapolating this to a "large population" via the law of large numbers.  The first is giving you a counterfactual statement based on smoking or not smoking for a single person and the latter is giving you a counterfactual statement for smoking or not smoking for a large group of people ("everybody vs nobody").  The latter is approximately correct so long as the population in question is large (as is the case for the population of Germany) and the individual effects can be considered to be either independent or close to independent.  (Here I set aside the question of adequacy of the model, discussed in the other answer here.)  Either of these methods of presentation capture an important aspect of the inferred causal effect, but one frames this as an individual effect and the other frames it as an aggregated effect in a larger society.  Both will have their uses, but the latter is typically more useful in communicating with certain influential classes of people who have the power to influence behavioural-change at a social level.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer (+1). For individual decision-making, other causal analyses can be used (e.g., estimating conditional ATEs).

Answer (score 3):

I think the distinction you're not making is for model correctness. Posit a probability model for child's weight. In simplest terms, statement 1 and 2 are equivalent *only if*:

(1) $$ \text{Weight}_i = \vec{\alpha}_m \mathbf{X}_i + \beta_m \text{ Maternal Smoking} + \epsilon$$

Where $\mathbf{X}_i $ represents the baseline (non-smoking characteristics) risk factors for low birth weight including features such as maternal age, polybirth, maternal parity, maternal weight, etc. $\epsilon$ is a random error term. Here $\beta$ is the value of -200g with Maternal Smoking = 1 represents a mother who smokes. Subscript (m) denotes marginal effects.

A more complex model may have:

(2) $$ \text{Weight}_i = \vec{\alpha}_c\mathbf{X}_i + \beta_c \text{ Maternal Smoking} + \gamma_i \mathbf{X}_i \text{ Maternal Smoking} + \epsilon$$

Where the effect $\gamma_i \mathbf{X}_i \text{ Maternal Smoking}$ represents interactions between the smoking risk factors and baseline characteristics - high maternal weight and smoking may not have additive effects due to synergistic mechanisms like poor placental development, incidence of preeclampsia, etc. Subscript (c) denotes conditional effects.

In this case, if one fits model 1 when in fact model 2 is true, it is possible through the balance of covariates that $\beta_m$ is estimated to be 200, and further *it is true that the average gestational birth weight will increase 200g*. It is not true, however, that any given mother who discontinues smoking will gain exactly 200g in counterfactual birthweight. She may only gain 50g due to the predisposition of baseline traits and their interactions, whereas another woman may gain 400g of birthweight by evading emergent delivery (i.e. preeclampsia). The average individual treatment effect of smoking discontinuation is given by $-\beta_c \text{ Maternal Smoking} - \gamma_i \mathbf{X}_i \text{ Maternal Smoking}$.

$\beta_c = \beta_m$ only if the matrix of characteristics is centered.

This case is completely distinct from the notion that a mother, having all measured baseline characteristics held constant would, in a counterfactual reproduction, have a randomly distributed birthweight whose distribution is given by that of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

This ended up longer than I originally intended and I am kind of strapped for time, so apologies if I misunderstood your questions or answered sloppily!

I might be misunderstanding how you are interpreting statements (1) and (2), but to me it seems like (1) expresses:

$$ E[Y^{T=1}] - E[Y^{T=0}] $$

While (2) expresses:

$$ E[Y^{T=1} - Y^{T=0}] $$

Both are valid ways of expressing the ATE. Notice that estimating the ATE is inherently about contrasting counterfactual worlds. Essentially, if we (hypothetically) had a copy of our universe, we could give our study population treatment $T=0$ in one world, treatment $T=1$ in the other world, and then contrast the mean outcome in each world to calculate a sample causal effect. The same identifiability conditions apply to both researcher A and researcher B and both have the issue that they would need a second world to observe all potential outcomes for study participants. This applies regardless of how potential outcomes are assigned in each world. You can communicate the definition of the ATE either way depending on preferences or your research question.

Let me jump to point (4): What you are outlining here is a violation of the *stable unit treatment value assumption* (usually abbreviated SUTVA and also known as no interference). Essentially, if your study participant's potential outcomes depend on the treatment assigned to other participants, potential outcomes do not immediately translate to a causal effect. If some participant $i=1$ smokes a lot around other participants, such that $i=2$ and $i=3$ have their baby's birthweight caused in part by $i=1$, an individual causal effect cannot easily be defined, which means that the ATE cannot easily be defined. You are asking a very good question here, but the unfortunate answer is that this would be a problem in any study, including in a (hypothetical) randomized trial addressing smoking and birth weight. The reason that the causal effects defined by researchers A and B appear to differ is therefore just an unfulfilled identifiability condition.

About statement (3): Yes, you cannot know that an estimated causal effect will exactly apply to you, but interpreting it this way would be a mistake in other settings too. The ATE defines an operation on sample means. I do not expect an ATE to apply to me the same way I (obviously) do not expect to be the same average height or age as people in Germany.

Let us say we perform a randomized controlled trial to assess whether or not smoking influences birth weight in pregnant people. To avoid SUTVA violations, we only sample participants living far away from each other, such that they are not exposed to each other's second-hand-smoke. We then randomly either force people to smoke ($T=1$) or to not smoke ($T=0$). If there is no loss to follow-up, $E[Y|T=1]-E[Y|T=0]$ estimates the sample ATE, defined as $ E[Y^{T=1}] - E[Y^{T=0}] $. A 95% confidence interval around this estimate will contain the true sample ATE in 95% of studies, had we repeated the experiment many times. The same interpretations apply (under the identifiability conditions) to observational studies in causal inference, if they intend to estimate the ATE. In every randomized controlled trial we therefore have the issue that we only have an estimate of a difference in sample means (observational studies have the additional burden of being unable to guarantee exchangeability). Whether estimated ATE's apply to individuals depends on expert knowledge and the generalizability/transportability of study results. Not smoking during pregnancy is unambiguously good. In medical settings, a new drug that shows superiority over previous treatments might not be superior for everyone, but we expect it to be an improvement over current treatments on average and can make individual treatment decisions informed by the literature.

Comment: You are the first person in this copy of the universe to agree with me that (4) seems like a SUTVA violation. And I still struggle with the fact that Researcher A gets to make nobody vs everybody statements, AND ALSO make a prediction for the woman in Berlin using whatever model was estimated. It seems to me they can have their cake (i.e., imagine worlds with 100% and 0% prevalence, where SUTVA will likely be violated) and eat it too (i.e., assume SUTVA in their research). I still don't get that part.